# Flutter/Dart Asset not found error for images and fonts

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I've tried adding images and fonts to my flutter project. However randomly (it seems) it won't work for images and fonts. As in it will work for couple_start.jpg and test_image.jpg. However if I add another one I can't get it to display getting the asset not found error provided is my pubspec.yaml file and an image of the file structure

[image]

```
name: project_name
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.6 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  provider: ^6.0.2
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.9
  jiffy: ^6.2.1
  age_calculator: ^1.0.0
  image_picker: ^1.0.4
  http: ^1.1.0
  flutter_secure_storage: ^9.0.0
  permission_handler: ^11.1.0
  device_info_plus: ^9.1.1
  emoji_picker_flutter: ^1.6.3
  
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/
  fonts:
    - family: Test
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Gabarito_Black.ttf
          weight: 900
        - asset: assets/fonts/Gabarito_ExtraBold.ttf
          weight: 800
        - asset: assets/fonts/Gabarito_Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Gabarito_SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/Gabarito_Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/Gabarito_Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
    # - family: Agricons
    #   fonts:
    #     - asset: assets/fonts/agricons.ttf
       
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
```

this is the component where it should be loaded

```
import 'package:project_name/widget/ui_elements/wide_button.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RegistrationSuccessPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const RegistrationSuccessPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage(
                          'assets/images/couple_register_success.jpg',
                        ),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: -1,
                  left: 0,
                  child: ClipPath(
                    clipper: CustomClip(),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
            child: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    'Je account is\naangemaakt',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 28,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                    child: WideButton(
                      buttonText: 'Start met daten',
                      onPressed: () {},
                      backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(28, 185, 84, 1),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomClip extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    double radius = 390;

    Path path = Path();
    path
      ..moveTo(size.width / 2, 0)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(size.width, size.height),
          radius: Radius.circular(radius))
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(size.width / 2, 0),
        radius: Radius.circular(radius),
      )
      ..close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

At this point i've rewritten the pubspec.yaml file multiple times confirmed the images in an image viewer and run flutter clean etc till my fingers bled and I can't figure out why it won't find the image or the fonts

Comment: I've been there. It hurts! Sometimes the only way for me to somehow make it work is to close my code editor (VS Code) and restart it. Don't know if you've done that too, but delete pubspec.lock; flutter clean && flutter pub get; close your code editor; delete build (apk/ ipa); if using an emulator, close it and reopen, restart all tools and go at it again. You could pub get (or preferrably `Ctrl + S` in pubspec.yaml) again before building. Also do separate `assets/images/` from `fonts:`, I've seen that be a problem before.

Comment: Oh.. and just to add (after reading the post again), I find it's always better to do `Ctrl + S` at least two times in pubspec.yaml anytime you add a new asset.. It should help more often than not.

Comment: Actually, you need to stop the running application and re-run the app after you add packages of assets in pubspec.yaml. Only when you stop the running app and Press Run the added assets or packages will be embedded into the apk file in case of android. So just try stopping the app and run again.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions I tried them all, sadly it didn't work tried commenting out the fonts as well thinking this might be breaking my import.

Comment: It solved itself eventually after restarting my macbook  a couple of times thanks for all the suggestions and tips regarding pubspec file